# Why is null=null in mysql false?

Tags: mysql

Why does `SELECT IF(null=null, 'true', 'false');` return `false` but `SELECT IF(1=1, 'true', 'false');` return `true` in mysql?

Comment: Because `NULL` means "unknown value" or "anything".

Comment: @axiac Thanks about that. I encountered that because in a programming language e.g python, it's true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` in SQL is a placeholder for an unknown value. Because it is unknown it cannot be compared to other values, not even with `NULL`.

Read "unknown" every time you encounter `NULL` in a query and it will make more sense.

Regarding MySQL, the behaviour of `NULL` is documented: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: it was indeed `surprising` as mentioned in the documentation . Thanks though

Comment: The programming languages that provide the concept of `NULL` give it a different semantic. In such languages `NULL` is equal to `NULL` and in some of them (PHP, JavaScript etc.) it is even equal to `0` or `''`.